# Blackjack basic strategy statistics wanted

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, game-theory, card-games

I have developed a program in VB that calculates the odds and the basic strategy for the simplest case of infinite deck. I thought I was correct when I decided to do the same computation in mathematica. And the results are not the same??? In order to double-check my calcs I need data about the basic strategy. For example if you are allowed to stand only on your hand, what's the house edge? My mathematica calcs give 11.568% for the house. Similarly when stand/hit is allowed I got 0.2058% for the player which is obviously wrong. Similarly when stand/hit/double is allowed and finally when splitting is also one of the options.
Anybody with those numbers or links?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't know these numbers, but to what accuracy are your numbers reproducible on different seed? I'm wondering if maybe you have a tie cause you didn't take into account that if the player busts they automatically lose, and the positive edge you're seeing for the player is just noise (or maybe you're paying them a premium for blackjack).

Comment: I have found that the [wizard of odds](https://wizardofodds.com/games/blackjack/calculator/) website provides some useful info.  Doesn't sound like it has everything you asked, but could provide some help for some of  your scenarios. Additionally, he recommends the [wizard of vegas](https://wizardofvegas.com/) for asking gambling questions.